# Gmail API error 429 rateLimitExceeded even where is no any activity

Tags: gmail-api

I have a NodeJS application that integrate with the Gmail API.
When I try to access the Gmail API, I get this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "rateLimitExceeded",
    "message": "User-rate limit exceeded.  Retry after 2017-03-26T18:15:52.102Z"
   }
  ],
  "code": 429,
  "message": "User-rate limit exceeded.  Retry after 2017-03-26T18:15:52.102Z"
 }
}
```

I was wait for period, and try again, and got same error.
I was wait for few hours, saw that is no activity in the API console, I was tried again, and got same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what's happening is you're making too many requests all at the same time. You can see your error in [Gmail Per-User Limits](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota#gmail_per-user_limits). Consider using [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#exponential-backoff).

These are the possible reasons you're getting that error:

> **Concurrent Requests**
>
> The Gmail API enforces a per-user concurrent request limit (in
>   addition to the per-user rate limit). This limit is shared by all
>   Gmail API clients accessing a given user and ensures that no API
>   client is overloading a Gmail user mailbox or their backend server.
>
> Making many parallel requests for a single user or sending batches
>   with a large number of requests can trigger this error--as can a large
>   number of independent API clients accessing the Gmail user mailbox
>   simultaneously. If this limit is exceeded a HTTP 429 Too Many Requests
>   "Too many concurrent requests for user" error is returned. Your client
>   may retry the request with standard exponential backoff.
>
> This per-user limit cannot be increased for any reason.

Other reasons may include:

> **Mail Sending Limits**
>
> The Gmail API enforces the standard daily mail sending limits (these
>   limits differ for paying G Suite users vs free gmail.com users).
>
> These limits are per-user and are shared by all of the user's clients,
>   whether API clients, native/web clients or SMTP MSA. If these limits
>   are exceeded a HTTP 429 Too Many Requests "User-rate limit exceeded"
>   error mentioning "(Mail sending)" is returned with a time to retry.
>   Note that daily limits being exceeded may result in these types of
>   errors for multiple hours before the request is accepted, so your
>   client may retry the request with standard exponential backoff.
>
> These per-user limits cannot be increased for any reason.
>
> The mail sending pipeline is complex: once the the user exceeds their
>   quota, there can be a delay of several minutes before the API begins
>   to return 429 error responses. So you cannot assume that a 200
>   response means the email was successfully sent.
>
> **Bandwidth Limits**
>
> The API has per-user upload and download bandwidth limits that are the
>   equal to, but independent of, IMAP. These limits are quite generous
>   and are shared across all Gmail API clients for a given user.
>
> These limits are typically only hit in exceptional or abusive
>   situations. If these limits are exceeded a HTTP 429 Too Many Requests
>   "User-rate limit exceeded" error is returned with a time to retry.
>   Note that daily limits being exceeded may result in these types of
>   errors for multiple hours before the request is accepted, so your
>   client may retry the request with standard exponential backoff.
>
> These per-user limits cannot be increased for any reason.