# Getting 429 (Too many requests) Accessing GMail from Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, gmail-api, azure-logic-apps

Once a min (1,440 times/day), I'm reading a Gmail mailbox from an Azure Logic App.  After 2 days, it consistently returns 429-Too many requests.  The quota threshold is 20,000/day.  It has not run successfully since.

Comment: Have you checked your usage against the quotas? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into the threshold for Concurrent Requests of gmail due to the parallel actions of Logic Apps. This will also return the 429 error.

What are you exactly doing in the logic app?

Comment: Once a minute, the Logic App checks for new mail. When it detects new emails, it takes the attachments from each email and injects it into our custom project management system. I've since disabled that Logic app and attempted directly from C# code with Google's SDK so I could definitively know every time GMail is accessed. I continue to receive a 429 error, even when waiting 30 minutes between attempts. Because I needed to resolve quickly, I've taken a completely different approach. Rather that accessing via API's with token-based authentication, I'm accessing the mailbox via IMAP -that works.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota#gmail_per-user_limits), the Gmail API enforces the standard daily [mail sending limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852).

> These limits are per-user and are shared by all of the user's clients, whether API clients, native/web clients or SMTP MSA. If these limits are exceeded a **HTTP 429 `Too Many Requests`** "User-rate limit exceeded" error mentioning "(Mail sending)" is returned with a time to retry. Note that daily limits being exceeded may result in these types of errors for multiple hours before the request is accepted, so your client may retry the request with standard exponential backoff.
>
> These per-user limits cannot be increased for any reason.
>
> The mail sending pipeline is complex: once the the user exceeds their quota, there can be a delay of several minutes before the API begins to return 429 error responses. So you cannot assume that a 200 response means the email was successfully sent.

You may try considering [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#exponential-backoff). Here's also an additional link which might help: [Gmail API error 429 rateLimitExceeded even where is no any activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032692/gmail-api-error-429-ratelimitexceeded-even-where-is-no-any-activity)